# Resetting a MySQL Field value without user execution

Tags: php, mysql

I need to reset a MySQL Field value automatically at midnight. It is a specific column in a specific row in a table. I know how to do this in PHP but I do not know how to execute the PHP Script at midnight without someone having to do it themselves. Do you have any viable solutions?

Edit:--------------------
Preferably without using Cron Jobs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running on linux you would use a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

On most distros there is a command called crontab that schedules tasks for you and a specific format you need:

```
0 0 * * * php /path/to/file.php
```

**EDIT:** 
Wrote this before you edited yours :p I'm not sure there is any other way. Do you have a specific reason not to use a cronjob?

You may not even need to specify the php part if the php file is marked as executable i.e

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/file.php
```

Just do "chmod +x /path/to/file.php" form the linux command line

Comment: just curious if there is another way to do it. If in the future cron jobs are not available. I have tried to set up a cron job but it seems it cannot find the file. 

/usr/local/bin/php -q /htdocs/www/mysubdirectory/cron.php 

I am doing this as seen on http://www.modwest.com/help/kb5-125.html

Comment: sorry:

/usr/local/bin/php -q /htdocs/www/mysubdirectory/cron.php 

Is the cron job I am using

Comment: have you done a "which" to see if this is true location of PHP on that machine?

Comment: sorry, "which" is a command on linux/unix that shows the full path of shell commands. So from the command line if you do "which php" it should return the path where php is

Comment: Which is sh/bash/etc's command to find file location (as simle answer). Run "man which" on any sh-like shell to read more. I.e. you can read about it here: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=which&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE&format=html

Comment: +1 for the cron job. or, you can do it by yourself every midnight :)

Answer (score 1):

There are web based cron services too. Basically you set up an account and then they visit an URL of your choosing at a regular interval. On your server you set up a page that does what you need to get done. Preferably give it a unlikely-to-find-name like myjob789273634ahhh8s2nhw8sghusgf874wfu.php. You get the idea. (Remember that PHP-scripts timeout after like 30secs.)

Here's a google search:
**oops I'm new so I can't post URL apparently. Just search for "web based cron".

Good luck
/0

Comment: "Remember that PHP-scripts timeout after like 30secs.)" 

You can counter this with set_time_limit(0);

Answer (score 0):

You could write a job scheduler into your program that runs jobs in a cron-like way.  It would require a user to interact with the system to trigger, but it might be good enough depending on your needs.  This is much more complicated than just running a cronjob, and does not ensure prefect timing (since it wont run until a user hits a page).

You'd probably need to add a table into you database that would list the job, the time you want them done, and a locking flag to avoid concurrent attempts to run the job.  Each time your script runs, you'd check this table for overdue jobs and run them as needed.

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid in the first place. Thank you though.

Comment: Then I think you're back to cron.

Answer (score 0):

Asking how to reliably set off a script at the same time every night without cron (or a scheduled task, on Windows) is like asking how to make a dynamic website without a server-side language.

If your app absolutely relies on a script running exactly at midnight, cron is a requirement. If your users have a hosting company that (stupidly) does not permit cron, they're going to be out of luck.