# How to send on a specific day in php?

Tags: php, email, datetime

I want to a e-cards or something like that. The user can choose the e-cards, after chosen, he must enter the some fields like name(to and from), email(to and from), message and I want to let user to choose which date to send the e-cards.

How to send the e-cards on specific day? I need to write a script that run every new day? How to do that? Sorry, I am new to php... (but not beginner like not even know how to execute mysql query, get message from url etc)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you need a script that runs every day.  (Barring ridiculous maneuvers like trying to fake this by checking on Web requests.)  The usual way to do this in a Unix context is called a **cron job**; if your hosting provider is Unix-based, you should look into what they provide for making cron jobs available to you.  On Windows there's a parallel service called Scheduled Tasks.

Answer (score 2):

This is for *nix.
Let's say you have a php script that sends email on a specific day called mailer.php

```
<?php
    //mailer.php
    if (date("m/d/Y") == "06/02/2009") {
        mail("client@email", "Subject", "Body");
    }
?>
```

We are going to assume that you already have cron daemon running in the background.

If you have root access to your machine, then setting up a cron job is simple as editing a file.

Open up /etc/crontab file and add the following task:

```
1 14 * * * root php /path/to/your/scrip/mailer.php
```

This means, as a root, the mailer.php script will be running daily at 02:01PM. You can change the numbers to whatever you desire.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was disscussed here [resetting-a-mysql-field-value-without-user-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902277/resetting-a-mysql-field-value-without-user-execution/902929#902929)

I'll just reiterate: There are web based cron services too. This could come in handy if you only got a shared hosting plan and can't add cron jobs. They will call an URL at a regular interval that you can set. Usually very cheap. (Cheaper than upgrading to a root-access server anyway.)

Just search Google for [web based cron](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=web+based+cron&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g3)

ciao!
/0

Answer (score 0):

This is somehow complex. First it depends on your system. If it is Linux/BSD/Unix/Solaris then you have this handy utility as **cron**. If you are using Windows, you have **Scheduled Tasks**. Run your script daily (or as you wish) and check what cards you have to send today.