# I finally was able to use cron... but I'm not sure if it will work with my code. How can i change it?

Tags: php, html, email, cron

My webhost supports cronjobs. I am very new so I hav almost no idea what I'm doing. I scheduled cron to run a script that sends an email. But I don't know what to do! Here's my cron: `0 0 28 * *  php -f /home/a7269592/contact.php` Now how could I adjust my code so when It's the 28th, that code will send out an email. Here's the PHP:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{

 $headers = "From: Memory Jet <your_company@example.com>\r\n";


$to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
$common_data = $_POST["message"];
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $common_data, $headers);

} ?>
```

Here's the html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<html> <body><form method="post" action="contact.php">
 Email: <input name="email" type="text"><br> name:<br> 
<textarea name="name" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br> 
Message:<br> <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br>
 <input type="submit"> </form> <body> <html>
</body>
```

So how would I change the php so that cron would schedule it?? Thanks in advance! -Ben

Comment: This will not do what you want it to. You need to re-architect your code.

Comment: oh i see... but how would I do that??

Comment: First you need to figure out what you want it to do.

Comment: Rather than being the response to an HTML form, `contact.php` should simply use the `mail` function directly, with you inputting the values you need rather than grabbing them from `$_POST`.

Comment: would this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913685/how-to-send-on-a-specific-day-in-php The second answer

Comment: Yes, it should work, but if your cronjob is already scheduled on the 28th (and not more), you can leave the if statement out. So you only need `<?php mail('to@example.com', 'hi', 'works');` (but watch devdRew’s post below, I think he’s right in what you’re trying to do).

Comment: @Aufziehvogel, would the cronjob work with my php code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not so far, i was in exactly the same situation. To my mind, you're trying to deligate mailing from exactly "at posting moment" to scheduled timetable. So that, first that you need to know is:

**WHEN YOU'RE RUNNING CRON YOU HAVE NO ACCESS TO $_SERVER, $_POST, and other global variables**

That's because you run PHP, NOT through the server, which is the AUTHOR of the global variables.

So, you need to create temporary storage for your mail, such as an mail task file (might be problem with at-execute time appending tasks, for example if you cron mailer sends mails, and at the same moment your frontend PHP script wants to add some tasks, so that the task file might me corrupted) or DB, or whatever your imagination can do.

After that, you need to set up your cron task, which would take for example first 500 mail tasks and mails it. Sure, you can mail all mail tasks at this moment, not a problem.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: how would I make a mail task file? What would be involved?

Comment: It's just a text file, in my case that was a serialized array of letters with such fields as: **to, subject, text, from, when**. Every time someones mails you through your method you will open file, unserialize data to some $var, adding letter with meta-information $var[], and then serialize it back to the file, (file_put_contents('/my/location/of/mail/tasks', serialize($var))). When cron script will run, it unserialize array of letters stored in mail task file, and just make foreach cycle, if there is no partition for chunk-based mailing.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you are trying to do, but are you planning for it only to send an email if it the 28th or store it and send it on the 28th? If you are using the first option you should change it so it says this.

```
<?php   
$today = getdate()
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $today['mday'] == 28)
{

$headers = "From: Memory Jet <your_company@example.com>\r\n";


$to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
$common_data = $_POST["message"];
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $common_data, $headers);

} ?>
```

As for the storing, the comments are right, you should re-architect your code. The crontab will run the code without gettimg data from the form - web based and CLI requests are handled diffirently. I would definetely add another file to handle the form request and right it to a form or database. The one run by the crontab would read from that file or database.